# ¿Algun evento o forma para deseleccionar un select tag?

Tags: php, javascript, select, eventos

Tengo un `php` con `select`, pero necesito que mediante un evento o algo, se pueda resetear o deseleccionar. Intente con `onkeyup` pero al parecer no puedo funciona este evento con este tag.

Comment: Un select no se puede deseleccionar porque de por si siempre tendra por defecto una seleccion asignada, por defecto siempre el item seleccionado sera el primero y no, no puedes deseleccionarlos, en su lugar lo que yo haria seria crear como primer `<option>` del select, un `<option>` en blanco (sin informacion), que seria lo mas parecido a poder deseleccionar el option, ya que de por si un select `NO` se puede deseleccionar. en su lugar le das al usuario la opcion de seleccionar el campo en blanco del select (asi lo he visto en muchas paginas).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplemente selecciona un elemento de la lista con `select.selectedIndex = 0;` cuando se lance el evento que desees, por ejemplo: Al hacer clic en un botón o cuando escribas en otro campo de texto.

```js
// Al hacer clic en botón
document.querySelector('#mi-boton').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector('#mi-select').selectedIndex = 0;
});
// Al hacer escribir en el campo de texto
document.querySelector('#mi-texto').addEventListener('input', () => {
    document.querySelector('#mi-select').selectedIndex = 0;
});
```

```html
<select id="mi-select" name="mi-select">
    <option>-- Selecciona --</option>
    <option value="1">Opción 1</option>
    <option value="2">Opción 2</option>
    <option value="3">Opción 3</option>
</select>
<button id="mi-boton">Reiniciar</button><br>
<input id="mi-texto" placeholder="Escribe para reiniciar el select">
```

Si lo que quieres es que no aparezca una opción seleccionada, asigna valor vacío en lugar del primer elemento:

```js
// Al hacer clic en botón
document.querySelector('#mi-boton').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector('#mi-select').value = '';
});
// Al hacer escribir en el campo de texto
document.querySelector('#mi-texto').addEventListener('input', () => {
    document.querySelector('#mi-select').value = '';
});
```

```html
<select id="mi-select" name="mi-select">
    <option>-- Selecciona --</option>
    <option value="1">Opción 1</option>
    <option value="2">Opción 2</option>
    <option value="3">Opción 3</option>
</select>
<button id="mi-boton">Deseleccionar</button><br>
<input id="mi-texto" placeholder="Escribe para deseleccionar">
```

Comment: en ese caso, ¿no basta con seleccionar el ```option``` --Selecciona-- ?

Comment: Pediste hacerlo con eventos. De cualquier forma, revisa la segunda opción para ver si eso es lo que quieres. Funciona en Firefox, pero desconozco si también en otros navegadores.